# How can i connect the Mics-5132 to Arduino Uno (Carbon Monoxide Sensor)

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

[image: datasheet]

hi. i don't know how can i connect Mics-5132 CO Sensor to my arduino.

plz help

Answer (score 1):

That is a very skimpy data sheet for the MiCS-5132 .  (Shame on manufacturer for not including isolation information between heater and resistor output).

Connect 3.2 volts (3.3 volts is ok) to pins 1 and 3 (heater). Keep in mind the heater will draw about 32 mA.

Pins 2 and 4 are the output.  The output is a resistor, whose value changes with the degree of detected gases. And the resistance is about 160 k ohms.

Wire a resistor (call it R1) from VCC (positive power) to your input. Start out with R1 = 150k  (anything from 120K to 180K). .

Wire the sensor (pin2) to your input (use an input that can do A/D conversion).  Wire the other side of the sensor (pin 4) to your board ground.

This makes a resistor voltage divider to your input pin. Your input pin should be an A/D converter.  The A/D converter input should return a value dependent upon the sensor resistance.

Experiment with different values for R1, to get the input range that you desire.